# How i can route from jquery to controller api?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core, routes, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an issue i cant solve.

I have a textbox. For this textbox i have an jquery autocomplete function. Jquery is working but get
the error code 404 so my routing doesnt work somehow.
I hope somebody can help me.
Thank you

Jquery

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#TabakName").autocomplete({
            source: 'api/tabaksuche/search',
           
        });
    });
</script>
```

Controller

```
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class TabakSucheController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly HookahContext hookahContext;

        
        public TabakSucheController(HookahContext _hookahContext)
        {
            hookahContext = _hookahContext;
        }

        [Produces("application/json")]
        [HttpGet("search")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Search()
        {
            try
            {
                string term = HttpContext.Request.Query["term"].ToString();
                var postTabak = hookahContext.TabakSuches.Where(p => p.TabakNameInventar.Contains(term)).Select(p => p.TabakNameInventar).ToList();

                return Ok(postTabak);
            }

            catch
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Startup

```
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
```

Comment: Did you check your browser's debugger to find out to which address this request is sent?
It's seems that you have to change your `source` parameter to `/api/tabaksuche/search`.

Comment: https://localhost:44347/api/tabaksuche/search?term=a this is the GET Url in the debugger. I tried /api/tabaksuche/search too but it didnt work out..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[HttpGet("search")]` attribute rewrites the routing of the controller. So, your action would be accessed at */search* instead of */api/tabaksuche/search*.
Changing your `HttpGet` attribute to `[HttpGet("api/TabakSuche/search")]` will solve your problem.

Controller:

```
[HttpGet("api/TabakSuche/search")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Search()
{
    ...
}
```

An advice: if you are writing your scripts in your Razor View, it would be better to use `Url.Action` helper, so your routing won't get lost.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#TabakName").autocomplete({
            source: '@Url.Action("Search", "Tabaksuche")',
        });
    });
</script>
```

The code above will always generate the correct route.

You can read more about [Url.Action Helper here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.iurlhelper.action?view=aspnetcore-3.1).

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked. I will definitly read about the Url.Action Helper :)